# Burying a fish as a Christmas tradition?

Tags: catholicism, tradition, christmas

To me this almost sounds like a joke, and I want to know if this is really a tradition...

I was at a dinner tonight with some vendors, one of whom was from New England.  He was telling the group about a catholic tradition of burying a dead fish in the back yard on Christmas.  He wasn't Catholic himself, and couldn't elaborate, but swore his friend's family did this as a tradition, and that it was a "Catholic thing".

Google is coming up blank, so I'm asking our Catholicism experts here:  Is this truly a tradition, and if so, what can you tell me about it? Origins, meanings, etc.

Comment: Never heard of it. It might be a "Catholic nationality" thing - not Catholic *per se* but maybe Italian, Polish, Austrian, or the like.

Comment: There is a dish from some European country where you begin preparation of the fish by burying it in the snow. Saw it on PBS once. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermented_fish

Comment: @davidbrainerd - I'm pretty sure that's it.He mentioned eating burying it one year and eating it the next, which I thought was crazy until I saw from your link that it's typical to let it ferment in an earthen pot for 6 months.  If you can work that into an answer to the effect of "No, it's not a Catholic tradition, but it is possibly a family tradition or cultural one", I'll accept it.  The question is "Is it a Catholic tradition?" and "No" answers the question.

Comment: Further research shows that lutefisk, another fermented fish (although not one made by burying it) is [a traditional Christmas meal in Norway](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lutefisk#Modern_consumption).  I'm sure this is all related, so you set me on the right path. For me the bottom line is this probably wasn't a joke, even though it's cultural, not Catholic.  You were helpful, thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Rakfisk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rakfisk) is a traditional Norwegian dish, which is made by burying trout or char in the ground for several months, and then eaten without cooking. [It is traditionally eaten around Christmas](http://www.norwaypost.com/index.php/culture/gastronomic/26069-we-want-you-to-taste-the-rakfisk-26025), but it is not a specifically Christian tradition (any more than turkey or mince pies). Since it is *eaten* at Christmas, the burying would have to have happened several months before, unless the fish is buried for an entire year. Norway is not a particularly Catholic country, so it is unlikely to have been a Catholic tradition.